# Error with using if else inside function

Tags: r

I have problem in using if else inside function, my code is like this:

```
ConvertWgtZooLS <- function(WgtZoo, LSWay, Pos){
    If(LSWay == 0){
      NewWgtZoo <- WgtZoo
    }else{
      BackPos <- BackMatrix(Pos,1)
      NewWgtZoo<- Ifelse((Sign(WgtZoo) * Sign(BackPos) * LSWay)>=0, WgtZoo, 0)
    }
    return(NewWgtZoo)
}
```

However, when I run that in R, error message appears as:

```
"Error: unexpected '{' in:
"ConvertWgtZooLS <- function(WgtZoo, LSWay, Pos){
    If(LSWay == 0){"
```

How can I resolve this? What is the syntax problem there? I checked many websites and seems the above if else syntax is correct.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is that an upper case "I" in your first "if"? R is case sensitive.

Comment: Oh yes! Good spot! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mrdwab - You should refine that comment into an answer

Comment: As to the error message: R thinks that `If` is a function, which gets a boolean value (`LSWay == 0`) as a parameter. The opening brace then confuses R, because it doesn't expect it.

Comment: @Dason, [done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11556038/1270695). Edits welcome.

Comment: @danielkullmann, good addition of why R gets confused here.

Answer (score 4):

The error in your code is that you have used `If` instead of `if`, and R is case-sensitive. Thus, it is possible to have another function named `If` that does something different from `if`, and, as @danielkullmann points out, that function is exactly what R is looking for.

The error messages that R produces are not always the most helpful, but in this case, it *does* point you very close to the problem area. It shows you where it got "confused" but it's up to you to figure out why!

After you've fixed that first problem, you'll find another one (for the same reason) on line 6, where you have written `Ifelse` instead of `ifelse`.

One last point: R is pretty whitespace friendly, so it is good practice to leave some space in your code to help improve legibility, particularly with `if` and `else` statements. Here's why:

1. I find `if (LSWay == 0) {` easier to read than `if(LSWay == 0){`
2. When using an actual function, like `sum(x)`, you *do not* usually add a space, making it easier to spot these conditional statements in large blocks of code.

The [Google R Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html) is an interesting read in this regard.